# Change folder name using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I have two sets of data that I need to be able to rotate between. In order to use the data it needs to be in a folder C:\Data so I was trying to create short script that would check which data set was in use (TX or CA) and rotate which folder set was using the "data" label, but it won't read the second line of either IF/ELSE clause. Is there syntax or something else I am missing?

```
IF EXIST C:\data_TX (
  ren "C:\data" "data_CA"
  ren "C:\data_TX" "data" )
ELSE (
  ren "C:\data" "data_TX"
  ren "C:\data_CA" "data" )
```

Comment: Syntax - `) else (` *must* be on the same physical line.

Comment: And if you read the help file for the `IF` command you would see what Magoo has pointed out to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF /?` to find out how this works. cmd.exe is not a free-form language. This is what the others are saying.

```
IF EXIST C:\data_TX (
  ren "C:\data" "data_CA"
  ren "C:\data_TX" "data"
) ELSE (
  ren "C:\data" "data_TX"
  ren "C:\data_CA" "data"
)
```